# weblogic.management.DeploymentException: Deployment could not be created. Deployment creator is null

Tags: ejb, weblogic

I manually deployed a war file.  I tried to start it in Weblogic and get a "failed to transition from STATE_NEW to STATE_PREPARED on server AdminServer."

Once I activated any changes and restarted I see that the deployment is in Failed status.  When I tried to restarted I get the error below.  Other people have been able to deploy so I don't think it's a problem with the war file.:

```
<Apr 2, 2012 12:03:41 PM EDT> <Warning> <Deployer> <ISW-PC-LT> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1333382621250> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: Deployment could not be created. Deployment creator is null.
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.createDeployment(BasicDeployment.java:154)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:201)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(StartOperation.java:94)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doPrepare(StartOperation.java:107)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:229)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:749)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1216)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:250)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:160)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:47)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
> 
Apr 2, 2012 12:03:42 PM EDT> <Warning> <netuix> <ISW-PC-LT> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <> <34607faaacd75321:-46eb8849:13673c91d14:-8000-0000000000000055> <1333382622159> <BEA-423420> <Redirect is executed in begin or refresh action. Redirect url is /console/console.portal?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=AppDeploymentsControlPage.>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that for some reason the latest version of WebLogic doesn't work with this war file.